# ¿Cómo encriptar una URL de YouTube con el método Has en PHP?

Tags: php, html, hash

Estoy insertando un video de YouTube en mi sitio web, lo que quiero es encriptar el ID del video, esto para que no obtengan el link del video directo, este video estará oculto. ¿Hay alguna forma de hacerlo? Hice un ejemplo pero no me funciona.

```
 <?php
$a = hash('ripemd160', 'RNZiwYW9ALg');
echo $a;
?>
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $a  ?>" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

¿Conocen algún método para hacer esto?

Al momento de cargar la pagina e inspeccionar el elemento del video obtengo esto:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/9c479b366acfd8e6c82b7a9704d252eebd1e48d1" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No te funciona, ¿Cómo?..

Comment: Al momento que la pagina se carga, el video no se encuentra, supongo que es por la codificación.

Comment: pues claramente, por que esa url para YouTube es incorrecta. Lo que podrías hacer es poner una imagen y al momento de darle clcik, que tu backend se encargue de decodificar la url y regresar la ulr decodificada con el video correspondiente.

Comment: Suena muy bien lo que comentas, solo no entiendo muy bien lo ultimo, sobre que mi backend se encargue de descodificarla. ¿Algún ejemplo que tengas? Me ayudarias mucho.

Comment: entra al [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128316/holas)

Comment: el back end es tu php y el front es tu javascript.... mediante peticiones usando ajax puedes jugar con los string... pero no podras enmacarar o ofucar la url del video tarde o temprano aunque sea en la pestaña de network o recursos se vera la carga del video desde la url de youtube...